# Android Progress Bar style

Tags: android

I am doing application for multimedia. At present i am concentrating on volume control. Is there any possibilities to change the style of progress bar into volume control. (IE) it should be looks like VLC volume control. pls guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you want..
If you want a custom look of your ProgressBar need a custom progressDrawable.

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_drawable" />
```

The easiest way would be to modify the original drawable in your SDK path (look for progressbar_horizontal.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The volume control is a system app, so it's not part of your app. Maybe you could intercept the "volume up" button, but I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: okay, but i already gave buttons to volume control, and volume control is working properly. the thing is i am looking out for graphical interface. I gave progressbar for volume control so that whenever i clicking the buttons progressbar shows the status. Every thing is working great. i want to change my progressbar style. i mean it should be looks like vlc volume control or just imagine some of the famous media players volume control graphical bar. pls guide me..